# Dynamic search in two tables in sql using php using a single input

Tags: php, sql, foreach

am currently trying to do a search in php and can pass single values through and get results. Now my challenge is that am trying to pass an array of values into a forEach but my loop only goes once through then end's with only the last value in the array. Can someone point out the mistake am making currently? I should note that the search is in two different tables so am using an alias for both.

```
if (!empty($postData->searchTxt)) {
  $nameArray = preg_split ("/[\s,]+/", $postData->searchTxt);
  $countNames =count($nameArray);
  foreach($nameArray as $index => $code ) {
    $whereClausePrefix === ' where ';
    $conditions = $whereClausePrefix." (ex.name like '%".$code."%') or ex.surname like '%".$code."%' or u.user_email like '%".$code."%' ";
    if ($whereClausePrefix === ' where ') {
      $whereClausePrefix === ' and ';
    }
  }
  echo $conditions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't append conditions. you reset it in every iteration.

```
if (!empty($postData->searchTxt)) {
  $nameArray = preg_split ("/[\s,]+/", $postData->searchTxt);
  $whereClausePrefix === ' where ';
  $countNames =count($nameArray);
  foreach($nameArray as $index => $code ) {
    $conditions = $conditions ." ". $whereClausePrefix." (ex.name like '%".$code."%') or ex.surname like '%".$code."%' or u.user_email like '%".$code."%' ";
    if ($whereClausePrefix === ' where ') {
      $whereClausePrefix === ' and ';
    }
  }
  echo $conditions;
}
```

you also need to move `$whereClause` variable to outside of your loop. because you reinitialize it to `'where'` after set it to `'and'`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. That worked out perfectly.

Comment: @BrianTananganjiManda glad to hear that. can you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow below code and add or/and condition depend on your requirement in

```
if ($conditions != '') {
       $conditions = $conditions . " or ";
    }
```

Modified code at below and you will try:
Where try to add all conditions with Or and at last concatenation with where clause.

```
if (!empty($postData->searchTxt)) {
  $nameArray = preg_split ("/[\s,]+/", $postData->searchTxt);

  $countNames =count($nameArray);
  foreach($nameArray as $index => $code ) {
    if ($conditions != '') {
       $conditions = $conditions . " or ";
    }
    $conditions = $conditions . " ((ex.name like '%".$code."%') or ex.surname like '%".$code."%' or u.user_email like '%".$code."%') ";    
  }

  if ($conditions != '') {
      $conditions = ' where ' . $conditions;
  }

  echo $conditions;
}
```

Comment: I tried you code out and had a few problems implementing it so i modified it a bit.

Comment: Forward me with modified code. So, i will update and it's helpful other's.

Comment: I can not directly forward you the code but please look above this text and see the code I have used. I have done a test on it and it works but if you got any suggestions on how to make it better please feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answer. Adding the $conditions again allowed the text to be loop through depending on the number of values in the array. In addition the if statement checking if the $conditions is not now was reset to and to help add more additional statements to my first array values search parameter. Find below the updated code. Hope this helps others out there too.

```
  if (!empty($postData->searchTxt)) {
        $nameArray = preg_split ("/[\s,]+/", $postData->searchTxt);
        foreach($nameArray as $index => $code ) {
          if ($conditions != '') {
            $whereClausePrefix = ' and ';
          }
          $conditions = $conditions ." ". $whereClausePrefix." (ex.name like '%".$code."%' or ex.surname like '%".$code."%' or u.user_email like '%".$code."%') ";
        }
      }

      echo $conditions;
```